# Azure SQL Server Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

Currently ran into a bug? on a SQL Managed Instance in Azure. On SSMS whenever we create a Login to associate with a user we dont see that login on the security tab on SSMS but do see the user on the database, is this by default in SQL Managed Instance? or is there a way to find an associated login to a database user, a view or dmv perhaps?

Comment: Hi please what is your SSMS version ?  have you try to refresh connection ?

Comment: I have SQL SSMS version 17.4 and yes we have tried to refresh connection, the create login from external provider when run works without no issue but when you look in security logins on SSMS it does not show up.

Comment: Hi in my case i have SSMS 17.9.1 and the Login was shown on Sécurity --> Connection of SQL Server Azure (*****.database.windows.net)

Comment: Hi think you can try too update your SSMS to newer version the change log was at this link and it's speak about Login (Azure Database) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#ssms-180-preview---cumulative-changelog-through-preview-7

Comment: Thank you Pascal I will try this.

Comment: well just tried it no good, still doesnt show up.

Comment: Please install SSMS 18.x, although is on preview it has a lot of fixes for Managed Instances. SSMS 18 has the best experience for Managed Instance users at this time.

Comment: @SQLAstro :( i didn't know why it's show in my case .. maybe with SSMS 18.x but in my case i have only SSMS 17.9.1

Comment: Thank you @AlbertoMorillo that did it, if your ever at PASS this year i owe you some coffee and a drink :)

Comment: I am at MVP Summit now, coming back again to the US for me is not currently possible $$$, but thank you for your kindness and gratitude. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the exact script you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install SSMS 18.x, although is on preview it has a lot of fixes for Managed Instances. SSMS 18 has the best experience for Managed Instance users at this time.

Keep updating SSMS to get the best user experience with Azure SQL and Azure SQL Managed Instance.